# ASP.Net Open New Tab in Browser from CodeBehind

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, code-behind

I need to open a browser tab from a link that is given to me by an asp.net code behind.
Normally I would have a link and `target="_blank"`, but the link that I need is dynamic, so I must have the behavior of a `_blank` link from code behind.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have the data needed to create the link when generating the initial HTML, you can do something like this in the Page_Load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('MyPage.aspx?Param=" + Param1.ToString() + "');";         }
}
```

If you're waiting for the PostBack to get the required data to build the link, you can send javascript down to the browser via the ScriptManager:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //process whatever you need to to get Param1
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('MyPage.aspx?Param=" + Param1.ToString() + "');",true);
}
```

Comment: hi james what if I want to open this in new tab ? Please help

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`Target` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target.aspx).

Comment: No, you missunderstood me... I don't have a link. I have a normal ASP:Button and in CodeBehind I have a lot of ToDos (DB Query and so on). After finish I must open a link in a new tab.

Comment: Then you need to emit a Javascript call to `window.open`