# Open URL in New Tab Instead of New Window

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am using the following code to open the file with dropdown selected value from a url

```
Protected Sub ddlPS_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlPS.SelectedIndexChanged
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "openfile", String.Format("var w = window.open('http://foods.shakarganj.com.pk/pdf/{0}.pdf');", ddlPS.SelectedValue), True)
    End Sub
```

Problem is that when i select the Value from dropdown it opens the file in window and also refresh the parent page.I want to avoid the the parent refreshing and want to open the file in new tab intead of in new window.

Comment: In firefox this will work `var w = window.open('http://foods.shakarganj.com.pk/pdf/{0}.pdf','_newtab');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent page refresh use jquery to open link:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=ddlPS.ClientID %>').change(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var w = window.open('http://foods.shakarganj.com.pk/pdf/' + $(this).val() + '.pdf');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dropdown change is causing a postback to the server. You can avoid this behavior turning off the auto postback and binding a client script event to open the new window on a new tab.

The solution you need: [ASP.Net Open New Tab in Browser from CodeBehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530274/asp-net-open-new-tab-in-browser-from-codebehind).

Comment: This post is for hyperlink but i am asking to open new tab in chrome using dropdownlist.Anyone please tell  me about dropdown

Comment: The same logic, just bind an javascript event for each item that will open the link.

Answer (score 0):

In firefox this will work, add target `_newtab` on your `window.open`

```
var w = window.open('http://foods.shakarganj.com.pk/pdf/{0}.pdf','_newtab');
```

For IE you have to force users to change browser configuration, so that new windows will be opening as tabs

Comment: But sir i have to use Chrome please tell some abt chrome