# Open new tab from asp button's codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically I have a  inside a grid and when the user clicks on this button I want it to open a new tab on the same browser. I have tried everything and I feel like pulling my hair out on this.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530274/asp-net-open-new-tab-in-browser-from-codebehind?rq=1

Comment: How do you put the link in the gridview?

Comment: @Pedryk provided the answer I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the following HTML code for your button:

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://www.url.com')">Open</button>
```

Whether that will open a new tab or a new window depends on the user's browser settings -- this is not something you can control.

Answer (score 1):

You can style a `link` as a button in css.

The html code could look like this :

`<a href="" target="_blank">Open</a>`

Explanation:

`target="_blank"` - this will tell the browser to open your link in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try using
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "newwindow", "window.open('MyPage.aspx?querystring=" + parameter.ToString() + "');",true);

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This code. It works Perfectly..

**Response.Write("window.open('YourPageName.aspx','_blank');");**